# Почему не парсится имя в вк в теге (h1) (python)

Tags: python, парсер, вконтакте, beautiful-soup, bs4

Решил освоить библиотеку Bs4
Написал простой парсер имени человека, имя в теге h1, которая добавляется в cписок,
при выводе списка в консоль пустые скобки
Помогите решить проблему, код ниже

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    
HOST = 'https://vk.com'
URL = 'https://vk.com/judywb'
CSV = 'mypage.csv'


def get_html(url, params = ''):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'page_info_wrap ')
    
    info = []
    for item in items:
        info.append(
            {
                'name': item.find('h1', class_ = 'page_name').get_text(),
            }
        )

    return info


def save_dock(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline = ' ') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ';')
        writer.writerow(['Имя'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([ item['name'] ])


def parser():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        info =[]
        html = get_html(URL)
        info.extend(get_content(html.text))
        print(info)
    else:
        print('вк ебланы')

parser()
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно парсить ВКонтакте через `bs4`. В большинстве случаев от вас будут требовать авторизацию, что через `requests` не очень удобно делать. А ещё иногда будет captcha, с которой будет ещё больше проблем.
Лучше воспользоваться [API для разработчиков](https://vk.com/dev). Можно отправлять запросы через `requests`, а лучше воспользоваться уже написанными библиотеками, например `vk_api`:

```
import vk_api

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('<Ваш логин>', '<Ваш пароль>')
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()

# Получить информацию о текущем пользователе
vk.users.get()
# Получить информацию о любом другом пользователе
vk.users.get(user_ids=<id пользователя>) # Вместо <id пользователя> может быть список с несколькими идентификаторами
```